# URI - getHost returns null. Why?

Tags: java

Why is the 1st one returning `null`, while the 2nd one is returning `mail.yahoo.com`?

Isn't this weird? If not, what's the logic behind this behavior?

Is the underscore the culprit? Why?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    java.net.URI uri = new java.net.URI("http://broken_arrow.huntingtonhelps.com");
    String host = uri.getHost();
    System.out.println("Host = [" + host + "].");

    uri = new java.net.URI("http://mail.yahoo.com");
    host = uri.getHost();
    System.out.println("Host = [" + host + "].");
}
```

Comment: http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6587184

Comment: @hsz I just tried it on Linux too with JDK 1.6.0_15. I can reproduce it there too.

Comment: @hsz And I can reproduce this on my local Windows which had JDK 1.6.0_45.

Comment: So... is this fixed in Java 7 or in Java 8?

Comment: Host = [stackoverflow.com].
Host = [mail.yahoo.com].
i got this output when i execute your code and changing first url to stackoverflow.com...

Comment: @GVSharma Good. How is this relevant to my question?

Comment: you said it is giving null na...just i copied that part of your code and i run it in my pc it is giving host name right..?same result i posted in above comment.

Comment: @GVSharma The example you give is irrelevant. Read the answers below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @hsz it is a known [bug](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6587184).

But, let's debug and look inside the sources of `URI` class. The problem is inside the method:

`private int parseHostname(int start, int n)`:

parsing first URI fails at lines `if ((p < n) && !at(p, n, ':')) fail("Illegal character in hostname", p);`

this is because `_` symbol isn't foreseen inside the scan block, so it allows only alphas, digits and `-`symbol (`L_ALPHANUM`, `H_ALPHANUM`, `L_DASH` and `H_DASH`).

And yes, this is not yet fixed in `Java 7`.

Comment: took me way too long to find this post. You saved my week, thanks!

Comment: if you are working jdk 8 as of today .. this post is a life saver. not sure when this bug was fixed or is it still relevant. I had my docker container names with '_' 's in them.. and wasted around 3 days to find this post :(

Comment: wow thanks!
And it's not fixed in Java 17 as well ;)

Answer (score 3):

It's because of underscore in base uri.
Just Remove underscore to check that out.It's working.

Like given below :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
java.net.URI uri = new java.net.URI("http://brokenarrow.huntingtonhelps.com");
String host = uri.getHost();
System.out.println("Host = [" + host + "].");

uri = new java.net.URI("http://mail.yahoo.com");
host = uri.getHost();
System.out.println("Host = [" + host + "].");
```

}

Comment: I noticed this. The question was if this is expected or not. Turned out to be a bug in the Java API code.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's a bug in Java, I think Java is parsing hostnames correctly according to the spec, there are good explanations of the spec here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_host_names and here: http://www.netregister.biz/faqit.htm#1

Specifically hostnames MUST NOT contain underscores.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using: `new java.net.URL("http://broken_arrow.huntingtonhelps.com").getHost()` instead. It has alternative parsing implementation. If you have an `URI myUri` instance, then call `myUri.toURL().getHost()`.

I faced this `URI` issue in OpenJDK 1.8 and it worked fine with `URL`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, it is a known JVM bug.
Although, if you want to do an HTTP request to such a host, you still can try to use a workaround.
The main idea is to construct request basing on the IP, not on the 'wrong' hostname. But in that case you also need to add "Host" header to the request, with the correct (original) hostname.

1: Cut hostname from the URL (it's a rough example, you can use some more smart way):

```
int n = url.indexOf("://");  
if (n > 0) { n += 3; } else { n = 0; }  
int m = url.indexOf(":", n);
int k = url.indexOf("/", n);  
if (-1 == m) { m = k; }  
String hostHeader;  
if (k > -1) {  
  hostHeader = url.substring(n, k);  
} else {  
  hostHeader = url.substring(n);  
}
String hostname;  
if (m > -1) {  
  hostname = url.substring(n, m);  
} else {  
  hostname = url.substring(n);  
}
```

2: Get hostname's IP:

```
String IP = InetAddress.getByName(hostname).getHostAddress();
```

3: Construct new URL basing on the IP:

```
String newURL = url.substring(0, n) + IP + url.substring(m);
```

4: Now use an HTTP library for preparing request on the new URL (pseudocode):

```
HttpRequest req = ApacheHTTP.get(newUrl);
```

5: And now you should add "Host" header with the correct (original) hostname:

```
req.addHeader("Host", hostHeader);
```

6: Now you can do the request (pseudocode):

```
String resp = req.getResponse().asString();
```