# Hostname cannot be null error when using AWS transcribe

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, transcription

I currently have the code:

```java
public class ProviderTranscribeController {

    private AmazonTranscribe client = 
    AmazonTranscribeClient.builder().withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_2).build();
    final AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_2).build();


    public TranscriptionJob transcribeMp3(){
        StartTranscriptionJobRequest request = new StartTranscriptionJobRequest();
        request.withLanguageCode(LanguageCode.EsUS);
        Media media = new Media();

        media.setMediaFileUri(s3.getUrl("bucket", "file.mp3").toString());

        request.withMedia(media).withMediaSampleRateHertz(8000);
        String transcriptionJobName = "myJob";
        request.setTranscriptionJobName(transcriptionJobName);
        request.withMediaFormat("mp3");

        client.startTranscriptionJob(request);

        GetTranscriptionJobRequest jobRequest = new GetTranscriptionJobRequest();
        jobRequest.setTranscriptionJobName(transcriptionJobName);
        TranscriptionJob transcriptionJob;
        transcriptionJob = client.getTranscriptionJob(jobRequest).getTranscriptionJob();

        return transcriptionJob;
    }
}
```

But I am getting the error:

```
    hostname cannot be null: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: hostname cannot be null
    at com.amazonaws.util.AwsHostNameUtils.parseRegion(AwsHostNameUtils.java:79)
    at com.amazonaws.util.AwsHostNameUtils.parseRegionName(AwsHostNameUtils.java:59)
    at 



 com.amazonaws.auth.internal.AWS4SignerRequestParams.resolveRegion(AWS4SignerRequestParams.java:121)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.internal.AWS4SignerRequestParams.<init>(AWS4SignerRequestParams.java:103)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.AWS4Signer.sign(AWS4Signer.java:225)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1271)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1113)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:726)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:668)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:532)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:512)
    at com.amazonaws.services.transcribe.AmazonTranscribeClient.doInvoke(AmazonTranscribeClient.java:349)
    at com.amazonaws.services.transcribe.AmazonTranscribeClient.invoke(AmazonTranscribeClient.java:325)
    at com.amazonaws.services.transcribe.AmazonTranscribeClient.executeStartTranscriptionJob(AmazonTranscribeClient.java:289)
    at com.amazonaws.services.transcribe.AmazonTranscribeClient.startTranscriptionJob(AmazonTranscribeClient.java:264)
    at transcribe.back.providers.ProviderTranscribeController.transcribeMp3(ProviderTranscribeController.java:32)
    at transcribe.back.services.ServiceCollectHttp.convertBase64(ServiceCollectHttp.java:27)
    at transcribe.back.ApplicationHandler.handleRequest(ApplicationHandler.java:24)
    at transcribe.back.ApplicationHandler.handleRequest(ApplicationHandler.java:14)
```

I've looked up the hostname error and seen that its sometimes due to the regions being wrong but I'm pretty sure its correct as my s3 is working. Any help welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the issue lied down in the String passed to the awsRegion parameter. In the following code

if awsRegion is a String, it should use dashes as separators, e.g. "us-west-2", otherwise it should use Regions enum, e.g. Regions.US_WEST_2.

Alternative solution involves using withEndpointConfiguration instead of withRegion

example:

```
String ecrEndpoint = "s3.%s.amazonaws.com";
final AmazonS3 s3 = = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(String.format(ecrEndpoint, awsRegion), awsRegion))
            ...
```

Reference:

[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: hostname cannot be null when trying to obtain AWS ECR Authentication Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50720197/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-hostname-cannot-be-null-when-trying-to-obtai)