# URI.getHost() returns null

Tags: java, url, uri

This prints `null`:

```
System.out.println(new URI("http://a.1a/").getHost());
```

But this prints `a.1a`:

```
System.out.println(new URL("http://a.1a/").getHost());
```

If all URLs are URIs (but not all URIs are URLs) shouldn't a valid URL that has a host component also have the same host component (instead of null) as a URI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Javadoc:

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html:
>
> *Returns*: The host component of this URI, or null if the host is undefined"

OK, so why is the host part of your particular URI ("http://a.1a/") undefined?  Look at the RFC:

> https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt
>
> Hostnames take the form described in Section 3 of [RFC1034] and
> Section 2.1 of [RFC1123]: a sequence of domain labels separated by
> ".", each domain label starting and ending with an alphanumeric
> character and possibly also containing "-" characters.  *The rightmost
> domain label of a fully qualified domain name will never start > with a  digit*... *To actually be "Uniform" as a resource
> locator, a URL hostname should be a fully qualified domain name*.

Comment: Thanks. That answers why `a.1a` is an invalid URI, but how come it's a valid URL? Is it because of the next sentence in rfc2396 (which you haven't quoted): "In practice, however, the host component may be a local domain literal." - so in other words, `a.1a` is invalid because the last label starts with a number, but in practice this URL might actually be `a.1a.local.domain` which is valid?

Comment: Sigh... You're implicitly asking several different questions, including Q1) what's the difference between URI and .URL?, and Q2) why is Java URI.getHost() returning "null"?  The answer to Q2 is "because the Java URI class implementation thinks you have an illegal hostname, per the RFC".  This is arguably a "bug".  Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25993570/421195